# Opencv python show black image/intel logo on unvailable/in used camera

Tags: python, opencv

I only have 1 build-in camera.

When `cv2.VideoCapture(1, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)`, it shows the intel logo for non-exists camera index
[Intel logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmCS3.png)

When `cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)`, it shows a black image
[Camera Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mwohe.png)

What I expect is raise an exception when camera is not available in `cap.isOpened()`, but since it return Intel logo, the ret is return `True` value.

And for the black image, in my real use case there is a time counter and it will stop count when the black image is detected. So I cannot do exception by just throws it away.

So the question is, is there any way to detect the camera is in used or index is not esists?

Here is the code for test

```
import cv2

try:
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)  # 0 is the default camera
    if not cap.isOpened():
        raise Exception("Camera not available")
    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if not ret:
            print("Error reading frame")
            break

        cv2.imshow('Camera Feed', frame)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == 27:
            break

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
except cv2.error as e:
    print(f"OpenCV Error: {e}")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
```

Below is the driver detail of the camera.
[Camera Driver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0qTE.png)
[Driver details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6qCe.png)